# Qz heona “cvpxyr evpx” - how can I solve this?

Tags: cipher

Here is the puzzle:

> Qz heona “cvpxyr evpx”.

Please, can you help me solve it as I am struggling! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Applying a

> [ROT13](https://rot13.com/) cipher (shifting all the letters 13 spaces around in the alphabet)

to this text gives:

> Dm urban “pickle rick”.

Which refers to

> an [episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickle_Rick) of *Rick & Morty*.